# unset() works on unix platform, not in Windows 10

Tags: php

I have this code to parse through a remote TXT file. It works fine on a remote server which runs on unix, but on Windows 10 Apache, it does not get to the `echo <hr>Reached here...<hr>;` line.

This is the code:

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('unicode-13.txt')) {
    file_put_contents('unicode-13.txt', file_get_contents('https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/13.0/emoji-test.txt'));
}

$blocks = explode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('unicode-13.txt'));

// var_dump($blocks);

unset($blocks[0]);

$emoji = [];

foreach ($blocks as $chunk) {

    echo "<hr>Reached here...<hr>";

    $top = explode(PHP_EOL, $chunk)[0];

    if (substr($top, 0, strlen('# group:')) == '# group:') {

        $group = trim(str_replace('# group:', '', $top));

    } elseif (substr($top, 0, strlen('# subgroup:')) == '# subgroup:') {

        $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $chunk);
        unset($lines[0]);

        foreach ($lines as $line) {

            $subgroup = trim(str_replace('# subgroup:', '', $top));
            $linegroup = explode(';', $line);
            $parts = explode('#', $linegroup[1]);
            $icon = explode(' ', trim($parts[1]), 2);

            $var_codepoint =    trim($linegroup[0]);
            $var_status =       trim($parts[0]);
            $var_sub_group =    trim($subgroup);
            $var_emoji =        trim($icon[0]);
            $var_emojiname =    trim($icon[1]);

            echo "var_codepoint: " . $var_codepoint . "<br />";
            echo "var_status: " . $var_status . "<br />";
            echo "group: " . $group . "<br />";
            echo "var_sub_group: " . $var_sub_group . "<br />";
            echo "var_emoji: " . $var_emoji . "<br />";
            echo "var_emojiname: " . $var_emojiname . "<hr />";

        } // line
    } // subgroup
} // foreach
?>
```

I get no errors on Windows - I have verified that the `$blocks` array is populated on the windows test, as a `var_dump($blocks);` displays the array.

However, it seems that on windows, none of the code beyond `unset($blocks[0]);` is fired / reached.

I get no errors in the windows php error log, so I am not sure what might be going on.

Comment: What have you tried to debug that problem? Running a debugging session through XDebug is not that difficult, and even a `var_dump` right before that line you assume to not work should be simple

Answer (score 3):

Using `PHP_EOL` is wrong here. It will be `\n` on Unix and `\r\n` on Windows, but the contents of the remote file don't depend on your operating system — the file uses `\n` regardless. So just use `"\n"` in your code instead of `PHP_EOL`, and it will work. Currently it fails because the file doesn't contain any instance of `"\r\n\r\n"`, so the first `explode` only returns one "block" containing the whole file, and then you throw away the first block, leaving nothing.